# eliminar letras de una lista de letras

Tags: python

el problema es relativo al siguiente enunciado:

Escribir un programa que almacene el abecedario en una lista, elimine de la lista las letras que ocupen posiciones múltiplos de 3, y muestre por pantalla la lista resultante.

En el código solo consigo obtener lo contrario, me da una lista de los elementos eliminados.

```
abc = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
       'k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s',
       't','u','v','w','x','y','z']

abc = [abc.pop(i-1) for i in range(len(abc), 1, -1) if i%3 == 0]

print(abc)
```

Comment: nótese que la lista la podrías hacer con `abc = 'abcd...'; abc = list(abc)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema viene de la expresión que usaste para recorrer la lista, y no del concepto en sí que era correcto.

Si lo escribes en forma de bucle "normal", verás que sí funciona:

```
for i in range(len(abc), 1, -1):
  if i%3 == 0:
    abc.pop(i-1)
```

### ¿Por qué no funcionó la comprensión de listas?

En realidad sí que funcionó, en cierto modo...

Ocurre que al usar una comprensión como la siguiente:

```
[abc.pop(i-1) for i in range(len(abc), 1, -1) if i%3 == 0]
```

Suceden dos cosas:

1. Se itera por los valores de `i` y para cada uno de ellos se mira la condición, y para los casos en que sea cierta se ejecuta la expresión `abc.pop(i-1)`
2. Se construye una lista con los resultados que esa expresión haya ido retornando.

Debido a 1, la lista `abc` irá perdiendo elementos, tal como sucedía en el bucle `for` explícito. Pero debido a 2, irás construyendo una nueva lista con los valores retornados por `pop()`, que son los valores que has ido eliminando.

Al terminar la comprensión de listas tienes que `abc` ha perdido ciertas letras, y que has construido otra lista con las letras eliminadas. Esto podrías verlo si haces:

```
eliminadas = [abc.pop(i-1) for i in range(len(abc), 1, -1) if i%3 == 0]
```

Entonces podrías mostrar `abc` y verías que está completa, salvo las eliminadas, y mostrar `eliminadas` y encontrar ahí las que eliminaste.

Tu fallo fue asignar ese resultado de nuevo a `abc`. Al hacerlo, la referencia `abc` deja de "apuntar" a la lista original de la que habías eliminado elementos y pasa a apuntar a la lista resultado, que tiene sólo los elementos eliminados.

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de la trabajosa lista

```
abc = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
       'k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','q','r','s',
       't','u','v','w','x','y','z']
```

vamos a usar una más sencilla, que nos permita verificar los resultados:

```
abc = "12345678901234567890"
```

Las cadenas se comportan como listas en Python.

También suponemos que las posiciones se cuentan desde 1. O sea, eliminado las posiciones 3, 6, 9, etc., el resultado debería ser:

```
1245780134679
```

Entonces, usamos compresión de lista, seleccionamos todos los elementos cuyo indice no sea múltiplo de tres:

```
r = [abc[i-1] for i in range(1, len(abc)) if i % 3 != 0]
```

Como no queremos que `i=0` cuente como múltiplo de tres, empezamos el rango en  `1`, y luego le restamos uno al indice en `abc[i-1]`

Lo anterior produce una lista:

```
['1', '2', '4', '5', '7', '8', '0', '1', '3', '4', '6', '7', '9']
```

que podemos convertir en cadena con `join`

El programa completo:

```
abc = "12345678901234567890"
r = [abc[i-1] for i in range(1, len(abc)) if i % 3 != 0]
print(''.join(r))
```

Answer (score 1):

Voy a compartir otra alternativa, intentando mostrar cosas que no han sido mencionadas, con el fin de limpiar el código (y me permitiré omitir tantos detalles debido a que las otras respuestas ahondaron bastante):

Primero, si no necesitas que el alfabeto incluya la letra Ñ, puedes user el módulo `string`, el cual viene con las letras ya cargadas.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Ahora, si necesitas la Ñ, pues está bien escribir letra a letra como lo hiciste.

Ahora bien, el otro elemento que usaremos para darle más legibilidad a nuestro código, es la builtin function [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Con esto, y asignando unos buenos nombres, nos quitaremos la necesidad de usar esos feos `range()`, `len()` y `i` que, realmente, poco nos dicen de nuestra intención acá.

Nos quedaría algo similar a esto:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet


abc = [letter
       for position, letter in enumerate(alphabet, start=1)
       if position % 3 != 0]

# abc es una lista que contendrá lo siguiente:
# ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'y', 'z']
```